# Problema con clase Conexión

Tags: php

soy nuevo en PHP, tengo un problema con mi clase conexión y estare muy agradecido de la ayuda que me puedan brindar. el código es el siguiente;

```
class Conexion {
    private static $_dbUser = 'root';
    private static $_dbPass = 'xasasesa';
    private static $_dbDB = 'cobranzas';
    private static $_dbHost = 'localhost';
    private static $_connection = NULL;

    public static function getConnection() {
        if (!self::$_connection) { //evaluo si la conexion no esta establecida ------ self::$_connection / $this->_connection
         self::$_connection = @new mysqli(self::$_dbHost, self::$_dbUser, self::$_dbPass, self::$_dbDB); //establezco la conexion
             if (self::$_connection -> connect_error) { 
                die('Connect Error: ' . self::$_connection->connect_error); //Salgo de la ejecución del programa si no logro establecer la conexion
             }
          }
        return self::$_connection; //
    }
```

La clase funciona correctamente, la primera vez que utilizo la clase es en esta parte del código:

```
function __construct2($PsUsu_Ema,$PsUsu_Con)
{   $con=conexion::getConnection();
    // $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from tb_usuario where sUsu_Ema='".$PsUsu_Ema."' and sUsu_Con='".$PsUsu_Con."'");
    $stmt = $con->prepare("select * from tb_usuario where sUsu_Ema=? and sUsu_Con=Aes_Encrypt(?,'ULISES')");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$PsUsu_Ema,$PsUsu_Con);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($ciUsu_ide,$csUsu_Ema,$csUsu_Con,$csUsu_Nom,$csUsu_Ape,$csUsu_Dni,$csUsu_Dir,$csUsu_Tel,$ciUsu_Ciu,$ciUsu_Car,$csUsu_Cre,$csUsu_Mod,$cdFec_Cre,$cdFec_Mod,$csUsu_Est);
    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $this->__construct15($ciUsu_ide,$csUsu_Ema,$csUsu_Con,$csUsu_Nom,$csUsu_Ape,$csUsu_Dni,$csUsu_Dir,$csUsu_Tel,$ciUsu_Ciu,$ciUsu_Car,$csUsu_Cre,$csUsu_Mod,$cdFec_Cre,$cdFec_Mod,$csUsu_Est); 
    }
    else {
        $this->__construct15('',$PsUsu_Ema,$PsUsu_Con,'','','','','','','','','','','','');
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $stmt =null;
    $con->close();
    $con=null;
}
```

la segunda vez me manda el mensaje:

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\Palmez\model\usuario.php on line 78

la linea 78 es donde asigno el valor a la variable $res.

```
public static function get_Menu($iUsu_Car) { 
    $mysqli=conexion::getConnection();
    $res = $mysqli->query("select sMen_Pad,sMen_Des,sMen_Lin from tb_menu where length(sMen_pad) > 1 and sMen_Est='V'and iMen_ide in(select iMen_Ide from tb_menu_cargo where iCar_Ide=".$iUsu_Car.") order by 1");
    $menu[][]=" ";
    $f=0;
```

de antemano gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Me temo que el posible Warning mostrado , no se encuentra en el código que añadió a su pregunta, seria bueno [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: En 1er lugar, la consulta tiene **varios** errores de sintaxis. Escríbela así: `$res = $mysqli->query("select sMen_Pad,sMen_Des,sMen_Lin from tb_menu where length(sMen_pad) > 1 and sMen_Est='V' and iMen_ide in (select iMen_Ide from tb_menu_cargo where iCar_Ide=".$iUsu_Car.") order by 1");` Si `iCar_Ide` no es número, debes rodear el criterio por comillas simples. Y ten en cuenta que tu consulta es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL.

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar, la consulta funciona, la probé antes en el Mysql, en cuanto a la concatenación de la variable $iUsu_car decidi hacerlo así por que esa variable la recupero mediante una consulta (esta consulta si tiene una sentencia preparada) en otras palabras esa variable no es ingresada por el usuario.

Comment: ¿Corregiste los errores de sintaxis?, por ejemplo aquí: `> 1 and sMen_Est='V'and `... como puedes apreciar, omitiste el espacio entre `'V'` y `and`. También aquí, `in(select iMen_Ide from tb_menu_cargo where iCar_Ide=".$iUsu_Car.")` es mejor poner un espacio después del `in ...`